# For loop with date as iterator

Tags: .net, datetime, for-loop

I have the following for loop:

```
   for (DateTime dateTime = FromDate; dateTime.CompareTo(ToDate) < 1; dateTime.AddDays(1)) { .. }
```

While debugging I see the dateTime.AddDays(1) is executed but doesn't change the dateTime.
Any predictable reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AddDays** method returns a new date, so you should have something like this: `dateTime=dateTime.AddDays(1)`

Answer (score 3):

`AddDays` returns a *new* date - it doesn't change the *existing* value (it is immutable)

You could perhaps use:

```
dateTime = dateTime.AddDays(1)
```

For the middle term, you might also find `dateTime < ToDate` easier to read (at a glance) than `CompareTo`.

Answer (score 1):

AddDate returns a new DateTime where the date is added. You have to change it to this

```
for (DateTime dateTime = FromDate; dateTime.CompareTo(ToDate) < 1; dateTime = dateTime.AddDays(1)) { .. }
```

Answer (score 1):

`dateTime.AddDays(1)` will not change the value of `dateTime`. It will return a new object with the new data.

Answer (score 0):

From the [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx):

> This method does not change the value
>   of this DateTime. Instead, it returns
>   a new DateTime whose value is the
>   result of this operation.